Tkinter grid geometry manager weight configure doesn't work properly
I want to separate my UI into 4 part which is searching, discography, info, data & graph. Each part is inherit from tk.Frame with bunch of component inside it. I use grid as my geometry manager. Searching and discography are on on columns info and data are on 1,2 column respectively. I want my UI to show data part half of the screen so I set weight of column 0, 1 to 1 and weight of column 2 to 2. But the result it not what I expected.

Look like column 0 and 1 are fill to much space and column 2 doesn't expand like it should be
here's is my code associated to placing component
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    """Main GUI class"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.controller = None
        self.search = Searching(self)
        self.info = ArtistInfo(self)
        self.data = DataStoryTelling(self)
        self.disco = Dicography(self)
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(
            self,
            orient='horizontal',
            mode='indeterminate',
        )

        self.init_component()

    def set_controller(self, controller: 'Controller'):
        self.controller = controller

    def init_component(self):
        """Arrange component"""

        # search section arrange
        # ========================================================================================
        self.search.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=20)

        self.search.search_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.search_handler)
        self.search.detail_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.artist_selected)
        self.search.entry.bind('<Return>', self.search_handler)

        # Discography section arrange
        # ========================================================================================
        self.disco.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=20)

        # info section arrange
        # ========================================================================================
        self.info.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky='news')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Data story telling section arrange
        # ========================================================================================
        self.data.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=3, sticky='news')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=2)


I have tried to remove certain element in each section to find what effect sizing but it's still weird and not like my expectation are there anyway to arrange it correctly?

Try setting uniform=1 in those .grid_columnconfigure(...).

Weight by itself only tells grid what to do with extra space. If you have two columns with widgets of different sizes and you resize the window so that there is extra space, grid will allocate the extra space to each column, but it won't insure that each column is the same size.
If you set the uniform option to some value when configuring columns, however, grid will adjust the rows or columns to be of a uniform size. From the documentation:

The uniform option, when a non-empty value is supplied, places the column in a uniform group with other columns that have the same value for uniform. The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their weight values

The value that you use doesn't really matter. All columns with the same value for uniform will have a uniform size, adjusted by their weight (ie: uniform=1 has the same effect as uniform='foobar' for all columns or rows that use the same value).
For a comprehensive explanation of how grid manages the size of rows and columns, see How does stretching the window work with tkinter's grid geometry manager?
